# Is there a power series with $0$ radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> > Question: Is there a power series with $0$ radius of convergence?(doesn't converge anywhere)

I asked my teacher this question and he replied in negative, however he didn't mention any proof for this, saying it is obvious that the power series must converge somewhere.

I am not able to to grasp the "obvious" here. Is there any proof for this?

Comment: What is the definition of radius of convergence you are considering? I guess it would not be different than this: the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n \geq 1}a_{n}(x-a)^{n}$ is the number $r \geq 0$ such that the series converges for all $x$ within the circle of center $a$ and radius $r$ and diverges for all $x$ outside the circle, right?

Comment: Can you state the definition of "power series"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series

Comment: Zero radius of convergence $\ne$ Doesn't converge anywhere.

Comment: @Did Is differentiation well defined on such a series which converges only at a point?

Comment: You mean, is a function defined at one point only, differentiable at this point? Just check the definition of differentiability and this Great Mystery of Life should dissolve by itself...

Comment: I think , it is not differentiable, it has to be defined on the neighborhood of this point, should be continuous at this point and the value of function should equal the limit. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A power series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(x-a)^n
$$
is always going to converge for $x=a$.

In general the radius of convergence if the "size" of the interval where the series converges. A series will fall into one of three categories

1. The series converges for all real numbers. We say here the radius os convergence is $\infty$
2. The series converges on an interval from $a$ to $b$ (possibly including the endpoints). We say here that the radius of convergence is $b-a$.
3. The series converges only at one number $a$. We say here that the radius of convergence is $0$.

So there is always a radius of convergence. The set/interval where a series converges is always non-empty.

Comment: What is the radius of convergence?

Comment: @curious: I updated my answer a bit.

Comment: For the second category, the radius of convergence should be (−)/2.

Answer (score 5):

Your teacher is wrong. Consider the series given by:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n
$$

The ratio test tells us that the series diverges: $\frac{n!x^n}{(n-1)!x^{n-1}} = n x$. As long as $|x| > 0$, there is some $N$ such that this is $ > 1$ for all $n > N$, so the series diverges.

Comment: Your series converges at $x=0$. (Just as the professor said!)

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, the assertion that "zero radius of convergence" means "does not converge anywhere" is false. So the teacher was right that the series must converge _somewhere_, but somehow failed to impress upon the student that this is not the same thing as saying its radius of convergence is positive.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the radius of convergence can be $0$, e.g., $\sum n!x^n$. It will, of course, still converge at $x=0$, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ṇ^nz^n$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$. The radius of convergence in this case is zero.