# Does interval of convergence of a power series always contain the origin?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

In *Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences* by Mary L. Boas, it was stated that

> Since the interval of convergence of a power series **contains the origin**, $\sin x= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+... $ must hold when $x=0$.

The author is trying to demonstrate how to find a power series for a given function.

But this seems to suggest if a power series has an interval of convergence, it *will* contain the origin.

However according to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498340/is-there-a-power-series-with-0-radius-of-convergence), not all power series has an interval of convergence that contain the origin. Is the author being sloppy here?

Comment: I believe what was meant was that a power series will always converge at the point about which it expands. In the case of a Maclaurin series, that is the origin. (So the author is probably being sloppy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the power series has the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, then the intervall of convergence always contains $0$.

If the power series has the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$, then the intervall of convergence always contains $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

A power series $\sum a_n x^{n}$ can have radius of convergence $0$, but it always converges at $0$. When $x=0$ the series is simply $a_0+0+0+0+\cdots$ which is convergent.

Comment: What about $\sum a_n (x-a)^{n}$?

Comment: $\sum a_n(x-a)^{n}$ converges at $x=a$ and there are examples where it converges only at the point $x=a$.

Comment: So by origin, the author means not 0 but x=a?

Comment: Yes, I think she was thinking about power series around $0$ when  she made the statement.