# Power Series: radius of convergence of zero interpretation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-numbers

The power series $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty i!x^i  $$ is said to have a radius of convergence of zero in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498340/is-there-a-power-series-with-0-radius-of-convergence) post and in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86hJqV6THJs&ab_channel=ElliotNicholson) video. If you interpret the $R=0$ as the absence of any domain of $x$ where the series will converge it makes sense to me. However, this interpretation appears flawed, because "a power series is always going to converge for x=a".

So if you plug in $x=a=|x-a|=0$ in the series and consider $$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty i!0^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i! = \infty$$
it does not seem to converge to me. What am I missing? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confusing $0^{i}$ with $i^{0}$.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty i!0^i =  1!+0+0+\cdots = 1$$

Comment: How foolish of me, thanks for pointing out my mistake.